# Ask someone if they can NOT do something?

Tags: questions, negation

A pupil would like the teacher to not wipe the board as he's not finished writing down the lesson. Should he ask: "I'm not done. Please could you not wipe the board?" stressing the word "not"?

Answer (score 2):

What you have written is grammatically fine and understandable. However, I think this version is a bit more natural – especially in AmE:

> Could you please not erase the board yet?

Adding the word *yet* lets everyone know that the request to not erase the board is temporary. And I usually hear the word *erase* rather than *wipe*.

Comment: "**erase**" sounds like "*remove from the world*". Are you sure that's the usual word?

Comment: @SovereignSun - Absolutely I’m sure – at least for American English. [Behold the ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=erase+the+board%2Cwipe+the+board%2Cclean+the+board&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3). [Google the phrase](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22erase+the+board%22&safe=on). _Erase the board_ means _Erase [the writing from] the board._ English is tricky!